# Does gimp allow you to set guidelines?

Tags: gimp

I want to start developing canvas html5 games but I need to make Sprites. I need a program that let's me place guide lines and read coordinates. Will Gimp cut the job? If not what are my alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

Gimp allows you to set guides by percent or by pixel under *Image > Guides*.

AFAIK, the current pixel coordinates are shown in the bottom left corner of the drawing window.

I've used Gimp for drawing pixel art before and it has worked well and I think it'll be fine for sprite work.

Comment: Ok that's good but can you place invible lines?

Comment: What do you mean by invisible? The guides should be invisible in that they don't show up in your saved artwork.

Comment: And you can always turn off layers if you decide you need additional guidelines (for example, a baseline for the character's feet).

Answer (score 0):

I have used both GIMP and Photoshop Elements to create sprites using guidelines and grids on layers. Both work, I prefer Photoshop Elements but that is a very personal question. I have tried a few "sprite building" software packages, and found in the end they didn't really help much but YMMV on that.

The trick is to have a good workflow. I started with the animation key frames in single images, and then moved to a sprite sheet where I would set the guidelines and snapping to the sprite size values and placed them as appropriate. I keep background layers around to mark alignment as well, because you can always turn them off when you flatten the image for the game.

With the grid set up, then you can make flattened copies of each keyframe, snap them over a frame, and work on each successive animation. Be sure to name your layers clearly, and group where relevant, so the workspace doesn't get out of hand.

That's not the only way to do it, and it depends on the style you're going after. You can pretty much use anything (even MSPaint!) but the GIMP and Photoshop Elements are both more than sufficient if you take the time to set up your environment and make good use of layers to line everything up.

Answer (score -1):

I honestly preferred Corel Draw for any work like that, because not only can you set guides by x,y coordinates, you can also move shapes around the same way.  Plus, it's all vector, so you can make your pixel art whatever size you like.